# On hover change multiple elements data in vue framework

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm new to vue! I have 3 divs, All divs have a message data (One source)! I've bind a method, that when hover on one div it will change the message! The thing is working fine, but it change all div's message! And I know it's logical! But How can I only changed on that hovered element data! Not affecting others!

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mbmohib/90ug2kva/).

Html Is :

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="one" v-on:mouseover="change">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
  <div class="one" v-on:mouseover="change">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
  <div class="one" v-on:mouseover="change">
    {{ message }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue :

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue.js!'
  },

  methods : {
      change : function() {
      this.message = "Changed"
    }
  }


}

)
```

Comment: It makes no sense since `message` will be changed in all divs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create separate data bindings, one for each message div. There are a number of ways to solve this. The best solution depends on your use case. But, here's a simple solution:

Template:

```
<div id="app">
  <div class="one" v-on:mouseover="change('foo', 'this is a message')">
    {{ messages.foo }}
  </div>
  <div class="one" v-on:mouseover="change('bar', 'here is a different message')">
    {{ messages.bar }}
  </div>
  <div class="one" v-on:mouseover="change('baz', 'message for baz')">
    {{ messages.baz }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Vue component:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
    return { messages: {} }
  },

  methods : {
    change : function(key, message) {
      this.$set(this.messages, key, message)
    }
  }
})
```